# Guaranteed or faster way to find Torkild in filial bonds quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, skyrim-dragonborn

I am trying to complete side-quest *filial bonds* but I have a hard time finding Torkild, even after seeking him out in the suggested locations mentioned on the related [Unofficial Elder Scrolls wiki page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Filial_Bonds). I have encountered some scattered werebears here and there, but none of them was Torkild. The wiki guide suggests that the encounter will be completely random.

Taking into account that the game is old and ridden with bugs and glitches, my question boils down to this: **is there a guaranteed or efficient way to find Torkild, or is it futile and indeed a completely random event?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no guaranteed way of finding him, he doesn't even have a refID to travel to since he only spawns during the random encounter.

Out of all the travel points, the glacial cave point seems to have the best chance to trigger him.

However, there's a chance you may have encountered him somewhere and he's dead dead already and you just didn't notice the corpse.  Having the unofficial dragonborn patch will prevent this.

Finally, you can always use the console command to advance the quest:

> setstage DLC2WB01 20

You may need to add the letter to your inventory first:

> player.additem xx026562

where XX is the mod load # for your dragonborn DLC